# How to learn how many battery charges programmatically on iOS/iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, power-management

Is there any way to learn under iOS using C code how many times the battery has been charged?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not via any public APIs. According to the `UIDevice` documentation, it appears the most you can do is get the battery charge level, its state, and enable battery monitoring.

[Get Device Battery State](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW28)